# How to use a git clone project as an import library of another git project

Tags: python, pip

I have two cloned git projects in my directory, myProject and OpenSourceProject. I did a pip install of OpenSourceProject so that I could use it as a dependency within myProject, for example:

```
import OpenSourceProject
from OpenSourceProject import SubModule
```

However, I recently cloned OpenSourceProject from GitHub with the sole purpose of modifying some code (fixing bugs and etc). It is now in the same directory as my other git cloned project, myProject. Is it possible for me to import the modified git instead of still using the pip install version? And how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st, you still can `pip install` the modified version; just `cd` to the cloned directory and run `pip install .`

Or you can modify `sys.path` to point to the cloned code. See [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) on how Python finds modules to import. Change `sys.path` in your scripts or environment variable `PYTHONPATH` before running the scripts.

Comment: will a pip install of the modified version overwrite the previous version? For example I pip installed opensource and have been using it in my code. Now, if I go into the modified version and use pip install ., then the instances of opensource that I previously used will be running my modified version?

Comment: Yes, until a different project depending on the newer version of the *opensource* installs the newer version and overwrites your changes.Then you need to update your changes and reinstall.